# What is the fastest way to achieve javascript data manipulation for my problem?

Tags: javascript

I have an array.
Format :

```
let additionArray = [{
    "0-18":{
        "male": 48,
        "female": 55
    },
    "19-24":{
        "male" :41,
        "female": 52
    }
},
{
    "0-18":{
        "male": 40,
        "female": 53
    },
    "19-24":{
        "male" :45,
        "female": 59
    }
}]
```

I need to add 0-18->male for all indexes in an array i.e 48 + 40, similarly for 0-18->female : 55 + 53 ,
also 19-24->male : 41 + 45 and 19-24->female: 53+59,
there can be n no. of indexes

What I have tried :

```
let TotalMale = 0;
let TotalFemale = 0;
for (key in additionArray) {
       TotalMale += resultArr[key]['0-18']['male'];
       TotalFemale += resultArr[key]['0-18']['female'];
       //Similary creating for '19-24' age group male' and female
  }
```

Expected Output : 
  0-18-> male -> TotalValueMale,
  //similary for female
I don't want to hardcode the age and gender , is there any optimized solution ?

Comment: what do you want to do as opposed to "hardcoding" the age and gender. how will the age and gender be provided?

Comment: Are you just adding together all of the sub-objects values by key and grouping it together?

Comment: It will be provided in the same format.

Comment: This sounds a lot like "merge with add on values".

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please explain me your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with any number of age and gender:

```
var resultArr = {};
for (key in additionArray) {
    for (keyAge in additionArray[key]) {
        for (keyGender in additionArray[key][keyAge]) {
            resultArr[keyAge] = resultArr[keyAge] || {};
            resultArr[keyAge][keyGender] = resultArr[keyAge][keyGender] || 0;
            resultArr[keyAge][keyGender] += additionArray[key][keyAge][keyGender];
        }
    }   
}

console.log(resultArr)
```

Comment: I am trying to get the values based on ageGroup , 0-18 : TotalMaleValue, 0-19 : totalMaleValues

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how to create a function.

Here's an example based on your code. You might consider using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

```js
let additionArray = [{
    "0-18": {
      "male": 48,
      "female": 55
    },
    "19-24": {
      "male": 41,
      "female": 52
    }
  },
  {
    "0-18": {
      "male": 40,
      "female": 53
    },
    "19-24": {
      "male": 45,
      "female": 59
    }
  }
];


function countDemographics(additionArray, age, gender) {
  let total = 0;
  for (key in additionArray) {
    total += additionArray[key][age][gender];
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(countDemographics(additionArray, '0-18', 'male'));
console.log(countDemographics(additionArray, '19-24', 'female'));
```

Comment: Ultimate!! I love you bro ..I'll try it

Comment: @KedarKulkarni - just hit the blue "Run code snippet" button and it will run right in the browser. If that is what you wanted remeber to hit the checkmark button next to the answer.

Comment: I am trying to get the values based on ageGroup , 0-18 : TotalMaleValue, 0-19 : totalMaleValues

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to have the aggregated total of male/female across the age group?

In this case, you can try using `Object.values()` to get all the object values without the need of knowing the key and then aggregate them using `Object.reduce()`.

Here's sample code:

```js
let genderByAgeGroupArr = [{
  "0-18":{
    "male": 48,
    "female": 55
  },
  "19-24":{
    "male" :41,
    "female": 52
  }
},
{
  "0-18":{
    "male": 40,
    "female": 53
  },
  "19-24":{
    "male" :45,
    "female": 59
  }
}];

function getTotalByGender() {
  const total = genderByAgeGroupArr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const values = Object.values(val);

    values.forEach((val) => {
      acc.male += val.male;
      acc.female += val.female;
    });
    
    return acc;
  }, {
    male: 0,
    female: 0,
  });

  return total;
}

const total = getTotalByGender();
console.log('male', total.male);
console.log('female', total.female);
```

---

If you are looking to aggregate them per age group, you can do it this way:

```js
let genderByAgeGroupArr = [{
  "0-18":{
    "male": 48,
    "female": 55
  },
  "19-24":{
    "male" :41,
    "female": 52
  }
},
{
  "0-18":{
    "male": 40,
    "female": 53
  },
  "19-24":{
    "male" :45,
    "female": 59
  }
}];

function getGenderTotalByAgeGroup() {
  const total = genderByAgeGroupArr.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const entries = Object.entries(val);
    entries.forEach(([key, val]) => {
      const ageGroupVal = acc[key] || { male: 0, female: 0 };
      ageGroupVal.male += val.male;
      ageGroupVal.female += val.female;

      acc[key] = ageGroupVal;
    });

    return acc;
  }, {});

  return total;
}

const total = getGenderTotalByAgeGroup();
console.log('total', total);
```

Comment: I am trying to get total based on agegroup